# Get the name attribute of a span element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an span tag in my document.  I'd like to access it's name property, but it doesn't seem to be there.  According to [MDN Element Name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name) the name property doesn't apply to a span.

That being said the document.getElementsByName returns my span by name.

Comment: MDN is correct, the name attribute should be used primarily with form specific elements. If you control the HTML, you could use a data attribute instead. (For example: <span data-name="mySpan">text</span>)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you already have a reference to your span handy, just use [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

```
console.log(mySpan.getAttribute('name'));
```